# Rails: respond_with RESTful controller template after non-RESTful action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, respond-to, respond-with

Getting "Template is missing - Missing template ballots/submission" error when trying to add a "publish" action to an otherwise RESTful controller. Clearly it is looking for a `submission.html.haml` view, which doesn't exist (and shouldn't).

```
class BallotsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def index
  ...

  def publish
    @ballot = Ballot.find(params[:id])
    if @ballot.publishable?
      @ballot.submitted = true
      flash[:notice] = "Ballot successfully submitted" if @ballot.save
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not submit. Ballot incomplete."
    end 
    respond_with(@ballot, location: ballot_url(@ballot))
  end
end
```

I'd like to respond with the "show" action in this controller in both cases. But not sure what syntax should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do a `redirect_to` in there to specify the path:

```
respond_with(@ballot) do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to ballots_path }
end
```

(Replace `ballots_path` with your route.)